# How to do join two collections in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am actually struggling with this from a long time.

I have a sql query

select * from posts where post_uploader='$user_id' or post_uploader in(select follow_user_id from follow where follow_follower_id='$user_id') order by updated_at

Can anyone tell me how to do the same thing with mongo db?

I tried to do this but I am getting error in LocalField. It requires string where I am passing object.

postModel.aggregate([{
$lookup: {
from: "follow",
localField: req.user.id,
foreignField: "follow_follower_id",
as: "follow"
}
}])

Answer (score 1):

I guess foreignField's correct Field is  "_id"

```
postModel.aggregate([
{ 
$lookup: 
   { 
     from: "follow", 
     localField: req.user.id, 
     foreignField: "_id", 
     as: "follow" 
   } 
}])
```

but your question don't have enough information